# Variable sumproduct if in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a `SumProduct` result with `If`s in VBA, while using arrays and I get a type mismatch error. More specifically I want

1. when the range in HT column meets some criteria
2. when the range in HS column meets some criteria
3. to multiply HT column with HV column and subsequent columns

The code is the following:

```
For Day = 1 To DaysTill
    For m = 0 To Rot
        For n = 0 To StepsNumber

            RArray((Day - 1) * (Rot + 1) + m, n) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Range("HT12:HT1048576") <= RotArray((Day - 1) * (Rot + 1) + m)), --(Range("HS12:HS1048576")) = Day, Range("HT12:HT1048576"), Range("HV12:HV1048576" + n)) * PriceStepArray(n)
        Next n
    Next m
Next Day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guees you error occurs at this piece of code :

`Range("HV12:HV1048576" + n)`

you can´t add the value of n to a string, instead you need to write like following :

`Range("HV12:HV" & (1048576 + n))`

Since the `n` should increment the column- and not the rowindex you can use this like @OES mentioned in comment

`Range("HV12:HV1048576").Offset(,n)`

Sidenote:

`+` is used do add numbers (int, double, float, byte, ...)

`&` is used to concatenate strings

Comment: Thank you but I want to change columns and not rows.

Comment: the n is to column offset?

Comment: This won't work.. Range("HV12:HV" & (1048576 + n)) because you would extend rows... Use: Range("HV12:HV1048576").Offset(,n)

Comment: Yes I would like to change columns. I will use the advice of OES and tell you

Comment: OES I used what you said but there is still a type mismatch error.

Comment: would you please post the exact error? The code of @OES perfectly works

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos also you could split you line of code into multiple lies, so you can better see where exactly the error occurs

Comment: @FatTony The error is in the conditions. Is there a way to rephrase it?